# "width: 100%; max-width: 100%;" Is there a special reason to set both of these up?

Tags: css

```
img {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

I am making a responsive website according to the tutorial.

I know the difference between `width` and `max-width`,
but is there a special reason to set the `max-width: 100%`
even though they set the `width: 100%`?

Comment: No. It would make sense if you would set `width` with a different units (`px`, `vw`, etc...) or override the `width` from another place

Comment: It's worth a quick Google. It's helpful because max-width always wins for elements that will render larger so it's useful for wrapping things. https://blog.prototypr.io/what-even-is-the-difference-between-width-and-max-width-8f37b282c7f1 https://css-tricks.com/tale-width-max-width/

Answer (score 1):

I don't think. Cause, it is saying that image size would be 100% which means whole image. But, if you also use 100% on maximum width that would be silly. Cause, both don't need to use. Nearly both is saying the same thing. So, you don't have to use both simultaneously.

Programming is language that's why I used "say" word.